# Converting Date and Vector in to Timeseries

Tags: r

I have a separate vector of prices(r) and dates(d) the data is in order. I tried to convert prices vector in to time series specifying the start and end date and frequency .

```
timeprice=ts(r,start=c(2000,9),end=c(2014,8),frequency=12)
```

When I do this the series starts from 2001 and not 2000. Can anyone tell me the reason?

```
r
 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 
 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75

d
9/30/2000  10/31/2000 11/30/2000 12/31/2000 1/31/2001 
2/28/2001  3/31/2001  4/30/2001  5/31/2001  6/30/2001
```

Comment: Can you please add a small sample of `r` and `d` to your question

Comment: @RichardScriven I did that Thanks

Comment: Seems couldn't reproduce the problem. I could start the time series from Sep 2000 using the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no issue.

```
r = c(1587.62, 1586.19, 1573.66, 1550.37, 1558.89, 1574.17, 1602.98, 1633.43, 1664.14, 1702.75)
timeprice=ts(r,start=c(2000,9),end=c(2014,8),frequency=12)
timeprice
         Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2000                                                                 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37
2001 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17
2002 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43
2003 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75
2004 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19
2005 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37
2006 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17
2007 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43
2008 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75
2009 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19
2010 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37
2011 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17
2012 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43
2013 1664.14 1702.75 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43 1664.14 1702.75
2014 1587.62 1586.19 1573.66 1550.37 1558.89 1574.17 1602.98 1633.43
```